# Change keyboard layout for login screen

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, ubuntu-mate

I have changed my keyboard layout in my MATE session. However, when I log out (or reboot) amd try to log in again, the login screen still has the previous keyboard layout.

How do I change the keyboard layout for the login screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MATE’s Keyboard Layout setting takes effect only within the MATE session. It has no effect on the login screen, or on tty consoles.

First of all, make sure the new layout has all the characters you need to enter your password – else you’ll have to jump through some extra hoops to log back in. If necessary, change your password to something you that can be entered on either layout.

Now, from a terminal window, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and reconfigure your keyboard layout as needed. (Current settings will be suggested as defaults.)

Run `sudo service keyboard-setup restart` to apply changes immediately; otherwise they will take effect after the next reboot.

This will set the keyboard layout for tty consoles. On Ubuntu MATE, this also sets the keyboard layout for the login screen (other Ubuntu flavors may differ).